# ErrorException in tcpdf.php line 3103: Undefined property

Tags: php, laravel-5, tcpdf

I am using Laravel TCPDF service provider elibyy/tcpdf-laravel.
[Link to github](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel)

I have extended the tcpdf class.(Working fine)

Now i want to add a page in the pdf, but its showing this error:

> ErrorException in tcpdf.php line 3103:
>   Undefined property: App\Pdfs\Pdf::$inxobj

in tcpdf.php, the code is

```
public function AddPage($orientation='', $format='', $keepmargins=false, $tocpage=false) {
    if ($this->inxobj) {
        // we are inside an XObject template
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($this->original_lMargin) OR $keepmargins) {
        $this->original_lMargin = $this->lMargin;
    }
    if (!isset($this->original_rMargin) OR $keepmargins) {
        $this->original_rMargin = $this->rMargin;
    }
    // terminate previous page
    $this->endPage();
    // start new page
    $this->startPage($orientation, $format, $tocpage);
}
```

showing error in this line

```
if ($this->inxobj) {
```

Comment: did inxobj variable declared before?

Comment: Yes, when using the package: elibyy/tcpdf-laravel . The tcpdf.php file is generated in which $inxobj is declared. 

Also, solved the issue, turns out nothing was wrong with tcpdf or the elibby/tcpdf- laravel package.
Just had some error in the code. By mistake i copied the code twice for saving the pdf.                                                                                          Before using the method AddPage(), i used method Output() 
That's why, it was showing the error. 

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah! Finally an answer in the right direction! When calling `output()` twice in a row before request is ended, you'll also get this warning. For example: I want the binary data once with `output('doc.pdf', 'S')` for a special caching mechanism, and then output again to the browser. But the second output should then be done through the caching mechanism to work around this error.